# Getting data elements through match

Tags: haskell

I have an a list of data with the format `[(StudID,Int)]` where `type StudID = String`. Hence, I have a set of data:

```
marks = [("8",90),("10",100),("5",86),("3",45)]
```

I now want to obtain the second value based on a matching ID which is the first element in each tuple. For example, if the `ID` I'm looking for is `"5"` then I want the value of `86` and so on. I tried something as below:

```
getStudMarks :: StudID -> [(StudID,Int)] -> Int
getStudMarks studid [(id,mark):xs] = if studid == id then mark else getStudMarks studid xs
```

But I'm getting thrown

> Couldn't match expected type ‘(StudID, Int)’ with actual type ‘[(StudID, Int)]’

highlighting the `[(id,mark):xs]` section in my code

Am I doing the recursion correctly?

Comment: See `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b`. Currently, you aren't dealing with the possibility that `studid` isn't found in the list.

Comment: Why don't use Data.Map? It is efficient than recursive function. To find a element in Map, just O(log n) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 3):

`(id, mark):xs` is the list you want to pattern-match on; you are wrapping that in *another* layer of brackets that implies a value of type `[[(StudID, Int)]]`.

```
getStudMarks studid ((id,mark):xs) = if studid == id then mark else getStudMarks studid marks.
```

However, you also need to consider what happens if `getStudMarks` ever receives an *empty* list as its second argument, which will happen if `studid` is never found.

```
getStudMarks _ [] = ???
```

Compare your function to `lookup :: Eq => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b` (which, incidentally is all you really need here; change the type of `getStudMarks`, write `getStudMarks = lookup`, and you're done).

Comment: I'm only wrapping it to one layer of [] bracket [(StudID,Int)] instead of [[(StudID,Int)]]. And what do you mean by getStudMarks = lookup. I didn't understood that part

Comment: `(id, mark):xs` is *already* a list, defined by the `(:)` constructor. Wrapping it in `[...]` creates a list whose sole element is the matched list; it's identical to `((id,mark):xs):[]`.

Comment: `lookup` (which is already defined in the Prelude) is basically the function you are trying to define.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension)?

```
getStudMarks studentId marks = [ id | (student, id) <- marks, student == studentId ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursion should be

```
getStudMarks studid [] = error "No value for id"
getStudMarks studid ((id,mark):xs) 
    | studid == id = mark
    | otherwise = getStudMarks studid xs
```

Other possibility

```
getStudMarks id [] = error "No value for id"
getStudMarks studid ((id,mark):xs) = if studid == id then mark else getStudMarks studId xs
```

Inspired by [LearnYouAHaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion)

Comment: there seems to be an error going on in studId((id,mark):xs) = getStudMarks studId xs. Shouldnt it be id instead? I'm confused

Comment: I'm more familiar with the guards syntax in your first example. Would it be possible to cater for empty list [] in the guards statement?

Comment: You can also use the multiple notation in combination with the guards, so first line of second option combined with first option. On the other hand the second option is how usually Haskell is written.

Comment: It should not be `getStudMarks id ((id,mark):xs)` instead of `getStudMarks studId ((id,mark):xs)` in the last line, because this case is covered in the second line of the second option.

Comment: `getStudMarks id ((id,mark):xs) = mark` is not valid Haskell.

Comment: @DanielWagner Was not sure if Haskell also supports pattern matching, like Prolog